# settyp: Boolean to String (true and false are converting to 1)

Tags: php, string, boolean, type-conversion

PHP7: 
The function `settype()` converts the boolean literals `true` and `false` to 1. 
Why is `false` getting 1?

```
$foo1=false;
echo "<br>foo1: ". settype ($foo1,"string");  // foo1: 1

$foo2=true;
echo "<br>foo2: ". settype ($foo2,"string");  // foo2: 1
```

The function `strval()` converts `false` to an empty string and `true` to 1:

```
$foo1=false;
echo "foo1: ". strval ($foo1);          // foo1: 


$foo2=true;
echo "<br>foo2: ". strval ($foo2);      // foo2: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're outputting the return value of `settype()`, **NOT** the value you converted. Since the conversion succeed. settype returns `true`, and gets echoed as `1`.

```
php > $foo = true;
php > var_dump(settype($foo, "string"), $foo);
bool(true)
string(1) "1"
```